# Snap.svg in React - how to access the svg in a lifecycle method?

Tags: reactjs, svg, snap.svg

I have an svg map component which I want to update whenever the props change.
Adding and subtract classes on some of the paths... that sort of thing.

Snap.svg seemed to be the way to go. If someone knows a better way I'd like to hear it!

So here's my render method, and the two lines marked with frowns are the ones I want to get working in a lifecycle method such as `ComponentWillReceiveProps`

```
render() {
    var map = Snap('#map');
    Snap.load("images/map.svg", function(data){
        if (map) {
            map.append(data);
            const a2047 = map.select('#a2047');               <---- :(
            a2047.attr({stroke:'yellow', strokeWidth:'6px'})  <---- :(
        }
    })

    return (
        <div className="map" id="map"/>
    );
}
```

The problem is, `map` won't work anywhere else except inside this `Snap.load` callback. I tried several ways, using `state`, `window.map`, `this.map`... and I get errors such as 'select is not a function'.

How to get access to the map in `ComponentWillReceiveProps` ?

Or is Snap.svg even the way to go for this application?

Comment: Did this - thanks -- but Snap.load creates a new map with every change in props. Currently searching for the best solution...

Comment: Setting a 'loaded' flag in state perhaps?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are doing a direct DOM manipulation with Snap.svg and neither `render` nor `componentWillReceiveProps` is a good place to do that. I recommend you to do that in [`componentDidUpdate`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate) which calls immediately after component gets rendered. But this will not be invoked for the initial render. So we have to do this DOM manipulation in both `componentDidUpdate` and `componentDidMount`. To prevent repeating the same code, you can keep this operation in another common class method and call it from both `componentDidUpdate` and `componentDidMount`. Also, since your props have been updated at this point you can simply access them with `this.props` inside the new class method.

## Example:

```
// @sigfried added to answer his comment below
import Snap from 'snapsvg-cjs';

export default class Mermaid extends Component {
  svgRender() {
    let element = Snap(this.svgDiv)
    Snap.load("images/map.svg", function(data){
      if (element) {
        element.append(data);
      }
    });
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.svgRender();
  }
  componentDidUpdate() {
    this.svgRender();
  }
  render() {
    return  <div ref={d=>this.svgDiv=d} />
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks sir for making my structure better. It all works now. The original problem - how to get access to the existing map, was solved by using this.map = map

Comment: @dwilbank I'm glad that it helped you

Comment: Sorry to be dense, but could one of you (@dwilbank or @tharaka-wijebandara) post what the solution looks like? The part I'm least clear on is what goes in the render return. Is it supposed to be empty? (Then maybe remove the commented out stuff in the original question.) Is Snap really supposed to find it using its id? Wouldn't a ref be better?

Comment: @Sigfried thanks for the example. I made it simpler to understand in the context of this question. Yeah. `ref` will be better. I wasn't aware of that `Snap` also accepts dom elements instead of selector strings.

Comment: Great. Definitely easier to understand than my version.